# How to access class array variables in java?

Tags: java

So I have an class array (at least I think it is, am a beginner in java and programming in general) which has a nested class with a two strings and one char.

```
Employee[] emps = {
   new Employee(new Name("FirstName",'M', "LastName")), ...
};
```

I have methods like setid, setwage in the employee and need to use the array to replace the current existing code which has been coded like this:

```
Employee emp1 = new Employee(new Name("FirstName",'M', "LastName"));
Employee.setSize(Math.max(emp1.getName().toString().length()));
public static void empIDs(Employee empA,Employee empB,Employee empC,Employee empD){
       empA.setId(1); 
       ...
    }

    public static void printEmps(Employee empA,Employee empB,Employee empC,Employee empD){
        System.out.println("\nName"+" 
        ".repeat(Employee.getSize()-1)+"ID\tWage\tHours\tGross\tStart Date");
        System.out.println(empA);
        ...
    }
```

I tried emps[i] with a for loop but got an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: count is negative: -24
    at java.base/java.lang.String.repeat(String.java:3565)
    at Employee.toString(Employee.java:146)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:3367)
    at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:1047)
    at EmployeeDemo.main(EmployeeDemo.java:32)
```

and feel completely lost

Comment: What is getSize method ? Why is it a static method ? print `Employee.getSize()` before the .repeat and you'll understand, you need to leanr to debug by yourself

Comment: It is a method to set the number of max employees

Comment: It is a static method because my prof said to use it on getSize()

Comment: print `Employee.getSize()` before the .repeat and you'll understand, you need to leanr to debug by yourself : do it and tell us how much it values

Answer (score -1):

I am guessing your problem is about iterating an Array with objects.

It is exactly the same as for primitive data types. e.g.:

The method below takes an array with employees and iterates through all of them through an  enhanced for loop.

```java
     public void iterateArrayAndDoSomething(Employee[] employees)
     {
         for(Employee emp: employees)
         {
             // emp is the current employee and you can do whatever you want with it.
         }
     }
```

Or using a simple loop:

```java
         for(int i = 0; i < employees.length; i++)
         {
             Employee emp = employees[i];
             // emp is the current employee and you can do whatever you want with it.
         }
```

P.S: Try reading the Error Stack, there it says that the error is on the `.repeat()` method of the `string`. It has nothing to do with the loop, but still, the above information may be of importance for you.

Comment: Tried both of them, and an error of Illegal Argument for both. Here's the link to the program's code if that helps. https://replit.com/@RoshanLamichha1/EmpProgram#Main.java

Comment: You can't "guess what the problem is". Please answer only when you are sure if the problem and the solution to fix it. That code would fix something like an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and there is NO use of en array in the code